# Pointing map elements in QGIS via URL?

Tags: qgis, hyperlink, url

Is it possible to create a URL to display a specific location on a QGIS map and selected layers and elements?
I would like to link from an Excel table to a specific element on a QGIS map...

Comment: Maybe [a simple join](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#joins-properties) can help you with that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look at it!